# Processing: How to add multiple getchild() objects in an arraylist

Tags: arraylist, processing, get-childitem

I am trying to disablestyle() multiple children of an svg image with a mouse click. every time you click the next child gets disablestyle(). Only I cannot add multiple children in an array or arraylist. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a generic array list like so:

```
ArrayList shapes = new ArrayList();
```

and a typed array list like so:

```
ArrayList<PVector> shapes = new ArrayList<PVector>();
```

To add an element simply call `.add()`:

```
shapes.add(myPShape);
```

To check the length of the list use `size()`

println("shapes has: " + shapes.size() + " element(s)");

The first practical difference comes when retrieving data from the array list.
If using the generic version, you will need to cast it:

```
PShape firstShape = (PShape)shapes.get(0));
```

Also notice you use `.get()` to retrieve an array list element by index (instead of `[]` you might be familiar with from arrays).

You don't need to this for the typed version (`ArrayList<PVector> shapes`):

```
PShape firstShape = shapes.get(0);
```

There are cases where one option is more practical or more flexible than the other and this mainly depends on the scope of your program.

Personally for small programs I use a typed one (though in larger programs using multiple classes and polymorphism the generic one is more useful).

For more info on what other things ArrayList do check the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)